# Which ASP.NET technology would be best for a URL trigger filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webhooks

I'd like to write a URL trigger filter in ASP.NET that would accept a trigger request (in this case from a [Kiln web hook](https://help.fogcreek.com/9216/try-kiln-web-hooks-with-request-bin)), analyze the contents of the request, and based on the contents either throw the request away (filter it) or pass it on to another URL ([Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)).

There's really no UI to this filter so what's the best type of ASP.NET project to use: an ASP.NET Handler, ASP.NET Module, Generic Handler, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relatively simple requirement, so an HTTP Module would quite possibly work for you, and it'd be the most light-weight approach.

However, if it were me, I'd probably use [WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api), which is built for handling RESTful requests. This will make the "analyze the contents of the request" requirement much simpler, and probably give you additional flexibility if you want to transform the request before passing it on to Jenkins in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a typical HTTP Module.
You can register to a event at the init function and add your logic.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335968/Implementing-HTTPHandler-and-HTTPModule-in-ASP-NET)

[MSDN - Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719858%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)